# How do we deal with unclear questions having a deleted OP account?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, deleted-accounts

I came across this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/240513/mock-objects-real-issues-test-driven-design-with-java. The question does not have enough clarification from the OP, and now the OP account has been deleted.

Flagging may not help because the OP is no longer around to respond to the flag. How do we deal with this situation? Should I flag for mod attention or flag as "Not Clear"? I do not have VTC permissions yet.

NOTE: The one answer to this question would prevent it from being auto-deleted by the system. However, that answer has been deemed "incorrect" by the OP as is evident from their comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the post is dealing with a general question that doesn't have an answer yet, one approach is to be bold and edit it to make it a good question.  Yea, the OP isn't around and so it will never have an accepted answer, but if a good question can be made of it (even if you already know the answer), its 'better' than a closed question.

The be bold approach is often something for people who have 2k rep to do so that they don't hit the suggested edit queue (the 'radical change' rejection may apply to some of the suggestions) and are familiar enough with the site to be able to rewrite it.  If you happen to have less than 2k rep, it may be helpful to mention the OP is gone and you are trying to salvage the question.

As the question linked is one on P.SE, there is some guidance on such a radical rewrite at [What is needed to really fix a question (an Atwood transform)](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6744/40980) - note that is still a work in progress and not even faq-proposed.  If people do have suggestions for improvements on that, I would be very interested in hearing them.

On the other hand, if the question is about a specific problem or issue, such that someone reading it may not be able to properly clarify it, the thing to do is close it (which will likely ultimately lead to the [roomba cleanup scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78048/213963) deleting it some day - the 9 day script would likely be the one (closed, has a score of 0 or less, has no answers with score > 0, has no accepted answer)).

Flagging a question puts it into one one of several queues to be handled.  The 'unclear' one in particular sends it to the close vote review queue (other flags can send it to a low quality review queue or a queue handled by the diamond moderators of the site).

Comment: It must be nice for Jeff to have so many things named after him, e.g. "[Atwood's Law](http://www.reddit.com/r/atwoodslaw/)".

Comment: I see.. I didn't realize that "unclear" linked to the close-vote queue. Makes more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @metacubed duplicate, too broad, primarily opinion, unclear, and the various off topic reasons all lead to the close review queue.

Comment: Also.. "Atwood Transform".. there's actually a name for that?!

Comment: @metacubed It was first mentioned in [this question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/3898/40980) and refers to a rather heroic attempt at rewriting a now-deleted answer ( http://i.stack.imgur.com/jOreS.png ) and refers to the change from the original to the modified form of a question in [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to make something that is a poor question into a better one.

Answer (score 6):

When you flag posts, they're not handled by the original poster. Depending on the flag, they're either handled by community members with enough rep to review flagged posts, or they're handled by moderators.

If you believe that the question is unclear, then flag it as unclear:

[image: Screenshot]

Flagging a question like this will put it into the Close Review Queue for community review. Then users with enough reputation to vote to close will close the question, if they agree with your flag.

**Do not flag using "Other" to close questions**. Only moderators review Other flags, but it's not necessary in the case of closing a question, because the community is already capable of reviewing those flags. You don't want to increase the workload of moderators unnecessarily.

Comment: My concern is that even if the issue is "put on hold as unclear", there is no way for the OP to correct this. There can be no any further action out of that question. In that case, why not just close/delete the question?

Comment: @metacubed closing is the first step toward deletion. You can only delete closed questions. So vote to close first, and eventually either a bunch of users or a moderator will manually delete it, or the system itself will delete it.

Comment: @metacubed flagging it as unclear is the first step to ultimately deleting the question.  There are several checks in the system to give time for reviews (and re-reviews) to be done on the question so that things are not erroneously deleted too quickly.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info everyone!

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. updated, thanks.

Comment: Also, freehand circle.. yay!

Comment: The question is not guaranteed to be deleted. If it has upvotes, or up voted answers. (?)

Comment: @Raedwald is that a question or a statement?

Comment: @Cupcake ... a bit in between: a statement of what I believe to be true, but about which I am uncertain.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about if the OP is or is not there.

Flag the question according to the situation you are facing. If you believe it is unclear, then just flag it. If peers agree, it will be closed, and will get out the flow.

If you understood the question in a different perspective from the existing answer, then post your own answer and start it explaining why you think so.

Moderator flags should be raised for more customized (specific) situations, I guess.